# PhantomJS - can requests be made to my server from the webpage that phantomjs serves to me?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I'm using phantomjs with the goal of building a test runner that proves our application "works" by loading up our webpage and attempting a sign-in (which will fail, since I'm providing fake sign-in details). I was wondering though if there are any oddities about phantomjs that would cause a request to my company's server to fail.

My code to trigger the sign-in works when ran from the developer tools in the console of my webpage (running on my browser, separately) so I expect the code I'm running through phantomjs to work.  Since the request to my server is asynchronous, I created a delay to give my server time to respond before moving on, but it doesn't seem to matter how long I wait, the server never sends a response back.

Has anyone had any trouble / experience working with phantomjs and trying to do more than just manipulate the DOM of the page phantomjs loads? Should I be able to send commands to the page phantomjs loads just like it was a regular page loaded in my browser?

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Could be a CORS issue? Are you hitting the error handler or the request just hangs indefinitely?

Comment: Which PhantomJS version do you use? Please register to the `onConsoleMessage`, `onError`, `onResourceError`, `onResourceTimeout` events ([Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf#file-1_phantomerrors-js)). Maybe there are errors. It could be anything. Can you narrow down your issue?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, guys. My company's application uses socket.io for communicating between the client and the server and that is what hasn't been working so far. It appears socketio and phantomjs don't play nicely, as seen [here](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/issues/1746).  I'm going to try to use [phantom-socketio](https://www.npmjs.com/package/phantom-socketio) to make socketio work.